# PHP - Check if index already exists in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and am practicing by programming a very basic signup form, which dumps the info into a MySQL database. However, I'm having a problem where, even if the name is taken, my program still adds the account to the SQL table.
This is my code to check if the name exists:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysql_fetch_array($result) === true) {
     die("Error: Username has been taken");
} else {
//register account
}
```

Every time I run this, no matter what the name is, the program runs the block of code inside the else statement. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql` extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Also learn about `prepared statements`...

Comment: it seems you are mixing mysqli and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `mysqli` then use.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
 die("Error: Username has been taken"); 
}
else {
// register here;
}
```

P.S do not use `mysql_` functions **[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the table and add make the field unique.

Comment: I could, but I'd still like to be able to check if an index is there

Comment: Try with **mysql_fetch_assoc**.